# Limit number of executions of a python program

Tags: python

Hello
I made a program in python2.6 and converted to exe with py2exe.
I wish that could limit the number of times the
user can use, then this is blocked with a counter or maybe a library.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Either store the count in the registry or write it to a file along with the program.  Either way is easy for the end user to modify though, unless you manage to encrypt the count file.

Since it's an .exe from py2exe, there would be at least a low barrier if you used something like AES encryption with a string key stored in the executable to encrypt/decrypt it.  Enterprising users would still find their way around this by extracting the key from the executable.

Alternatively, you can have your program call out to a server you control and increment its use count in your own database.

None of these seems like a great answer to me, just providing ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Write the number of starts into a file and check it.

If you want a 100% secure and safe way to prevent users from starting your app more than 15 times, then you should not publish it. That's the only working way to make sure the user doesn't start it more than 15 times.

Rationale: Any good hacker will be able to dismantle your protection in a couple of minutes if he cares. The average user won't know where to start. So you can get good (99%) protection with little effort or 99.5% for a whole lot of effort.

Comment: With the minor addendum that once one person has been bothered enough to crack it, the crack can then be redistributed.

Comment: if the cracker can be bothered. Sales can be low because of a lot of piracy or because no one really wants the product... :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that very simply like:

```
import os
import sys

COUNT_FILE = os.path.join(SOME_PATH, '.myprog.count')
if not os.path.exists(COUNT_FILE):
    num = 0
else:
    f = open(COUNT_FILE, 'r')
    num = int(f.read())
    f.close()

if num+1 > 3:
    print >>sys.stderr, "You have exceeded your %d uses"%(num,)
    sys.exit(0)

num += 1
f = open(COUNT_FILE, 'w')
f.write(str(num))
f.close()
```

If you are trying to do this for some kind of "trial version" though, this technique is very easy to defeat. I think lots of Windows programs store counters like this in the registry.

If you're asking how to have your executable modify itself, I think that is a Hard Problem, and I don't know that anyone has ever made their trial version software work that way.

Comment: The program is made ​​for users with limited knowledge
pc programming and use.
is a test version, if this turns out to be way too good insurance
someone finds the solution or pay for it ...
thanks

Answer (score 0):

A compiled binary can't (easily) modify itself to keep track of something like this. You're going to have to write a counter to the registry or to some web API and check that counter on application (executable) startup.

Keeping in mind, this won't stop someone that determed from bypassing the counter- just a casual user.